# In Cordova Android, jsPDF addImage from Canvas Signature is not writing correctly when write to PDF file

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

This is DataURL from SignaturePad

```
var imageURI = signaturePad.toDataURL();
```

This is for Writing to PDF using jsPDF

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
var d = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, "");
var filename = 'sign_' + d + '.pdf';
pdf.text(20, 20, 'YES, Inside of Cordova!');
pdf.addImage(imageURI, 'PNG', 20, 50);
pdf.save(filename);
var pdfOutput = pdf.output();
```

This is for saving in Android

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory, function(dir) {
   console.log("Access to the directory granted succesfully");
   dir.getFile('sign.pdf', {create:true}, function(file) {
      console.log("File created succesfully.");
      file.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
         console.log("Writing content to file");
         fileWriter.write(pdfOutput);
      }, function(){
         alert('Unable to save file in path '+ cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory);
         }
     );
  });
});
```

But the Signature is not correctly write in Pdf.

when I draw in Signature
[when I draw in Signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWvpc.png)

but the Pdf in show
[but the Pdf in show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYUjc.png)